# VBA - Picking up a value from list without repeats

Tags: excel, vba, random

### I'm writing a code which chooses "x" client ids ​​then creates a loop that randomly chooses "x" ids ​​from a list, after this the code do a xlookup to get revenue from this clients, and finally sum all the chosen clients revenues, so far so good, but I don´t know how to choose randomly without repeating the previous id of the loop. I don't know if I was clear enough. Follow code below

```
Private Sub pick()


resultado = 0

For X = 1 To Range("G7").Value
valor_procurado = WorksheetFunction.Choose(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a1"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a2"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a3"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a4"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a5"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a6"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a7"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a8"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a9"), _
Sheets("lista").Range("a10"))

matriz_procurada = Sheets("lista").Range("a1:a10")

matriz_retorno = Sheets("lista").Range("b1:b10")

valores = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(valor_procurado, matriz_procurada, matriz_retorno, "-", 0)

resultado = resultado + valores

Next

Range("G8") = resultado

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using a While loop with a counter that counts down only if the randomly selected cell hasn't been selected in a previous loop cycle. You might need a helper column to mark the ones that have already been processed and execute your code only if the row hasn't been marked yet. The For/Next loop isn't the best solution here because it has defined endpoints.

Comment: This sounds like a nice solution, but I newbie in VBA (think you notice), And I have no ideia how create a logic that counts down only if the randomly selected cell hasn't been selected in a previous loop cycle. Could you please give a example code or send me a link of some tutorial? Anyway, thanks a lot... –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for if I understand correctly.

This creates a dictionary with the key being a simple index and the item the values in column B. It takes a random number between 1 and the upper limit, originally set to the last row. It then reindexes the dictionary removing the value that was selected and lowering the upper limit by 1.

I added in lastrow but you can hardcode that if you'd like.

tested with 10,000 rows, should be fast.

```
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim upper As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim randomizer As Long
    Dim total As Long
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    total = 0
    
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'assign a value to lr if you don't want the last row
        upper = lr
        For i = 1 To lr
            dict.Add i, .Cells(i, 2).Value
        Next i
        For i = 1 To .Cells(7, 7).Value
            randomizer = Int(upper * Rnd + 1)
            total = total + dict(randomizer)
            Debug.Print randomizer, total
            dict.Remove randomizer
            For j = (randomizer + 1) To upper
                dict.Key(j) = j - 1
            Next j
            upper = upper - 1
        Next i
        .Cells(7, 8).Value = total
    End With
```